# Is there a real solution for "can't connect to camera" issue on 4.3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera, 4.3-jelly-bean

I upgraded my Galaxy Notes 2 from CyanogenMod 10.1 to 10.2 (= android 4.3). Unfortunately the camera has continous problems - I end up twice a week or so with a `cannot connect to camera` popup when trying to shoot a picture.

[Many people](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%204.3%20%22can%27t%20connect%20to%20camera%22) seem to have this issue. [A similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39300/cannot-connect-to-camera-and-cannot-switch-to-camcorder-problems) some time ago did not get any answers. I even found a somewhow-working-workaround in the form of a permission-setting app (I cannot find the source anymore but will look around if someone is interested).

All this make the camera app more or less unusable.

- does anyone know about a working solution?
- would there be a way to install the previous version (which worked without any problems), without downgrading to 4.2.x, obviously.

Answer (score -2):

In my case was just an app. "Lantern" - flashlight using LED. After uninstalling that app the camera was OK again.