# Camera keeps crashing on Google Nexus 5 with 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: nexus-5, camera, 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Google Nexus 5 with Kernel 3.4.0-g2aa165e and build number MRA58N. (Android 6 Marshmallow)

Its not rooted or modified.

Just recently the camera keeps crashing. I click the camera button and get "can't connect to camera" message. The only way to start up the camera is to switch it off and on again. I'm travelling and take a lot of photos - Its incredibly frustrating when I just want to take a quick snap. By the time the camera comes back on, the moment has passed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Camera doesn't work on Nexus 5 running Android L](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/82300) / [Nexus 5 front camera not working](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68228) / [Is there a real solution for "can't connect to camera" issue on 4.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61443) / ["Can't connect to camera", Nexus 6 - Lollipop 5.1](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117070)

Comment: Cheers but it was working fine on 5.1, seems to be an issue with 6.0